# Send command to all connected clients

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy

I have a TIdHttpServer i must keep the connection open in order to send some commands back to the clients. I want to iterate when i press a button and send a command to all connected clients.

How can i do this ?

Comment: I use delphi xe 2 with indy 10

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can  use the `Contexts` property to get the clients and then using the `IOHandler` of each client you can send a message.

```
Var
  Clients : TList;
  i : integer;
begin

  if not Assigned(IdTCPServer1.Contexts) then exit;

  Clients:=IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList;
  try
    for i := 0 to Clients.Count-1 do
      try
        TIdContext(Clients[i]).Connection.IOHandler.Write(LBuffer);//LBuffer is a TBytes with the data to send
      except
        ...
      end;
  finally
    IdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;

end;
```